# Fullcalendar-scheduler updateEvent is note updating event with different ID

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, jquery-events, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am trying to update a event, one by one, but `updateEvent` update all events, all events have separate Id and _Id , first time it run perfectly for one event, but after first time,when we edit other events, every time it update previous edited values similar as current edited events. Using callback function `eventClick` for get original event.

```js
$(function () {
        $('#event_time_edit').daterangepicker({
            timePicker: true,
            timePickerIncrement: 30,
            locale: {
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY h:mm A'
            }
        });

        if (typeof ($.fn.fullCalendar) === 'undefined') {
            return;
        }

        var calendar = $('#rehabCalender').fullCalendar({
            schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
            selectable: true,
            header: {
                left: 'today prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'timelineDay,timelineWeek,timelineMonth,listMonth'


            },
            defaultView: 'timelineMonth',
            resourceGroupField: 'building',
            resourceLabelText: 'Categories',
            eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                var event = calEvent;
                
                $('#CalenderModalEdit').modal("show");

                $('#title2').val(event.title);

                var end = moment(event.end._i).format("DD/MM/YYYY h:mm A");
                var start = moment(event.start._i).format("DD/MM/YYYY h:mm A");
                var dateAndTime = start + " - " + end;
                $('#event_time_edit').val(dateAndTime);
                $("#event_time_edit").data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(start);
                $("#event_time_edit").data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(end);
                
               
                $(".antosubmit2").on("click", function (e) {
                    event.start = moment($('#event_time_edit').data('daterangepicker').startDate._d).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    event.end = moment($('#event_time_edit').data('daterangepicker').endDate._d).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    event.title = $("#title2").val();
                    event.desc = $("#descr2").val();
                    
                    calendar.fullCalendar("updateEvent", event);
                    $('#CalenderModalEdit').modal('hide')
                });
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');

            },
            editable: true,
            resources: [{"id":"7","title":"TRAINER","children":[{"id":"8","parentId":"7","title":"Static truck exercises","children":[{"id":"9","parentId":"8","title":"Crook Lying"},{"id":"10","parentId":"8","title":"4 pt"},{"id":"11","parentId":"8","title":"Bridging"},{"id":"12","parentId":"8","title":"Plank"},{"id":"13","parentId":"8","title":"Side Support (Side Plank)"}]},{"id":"14","parentId":"7","title":"Dynamic Trunk Control\/Mobility","children":[{"id":"15","parentId":"14","title":"Mat Exercises"},{"id":"16","parentId":"14","title":"Physio Ball"},{"id":"17","parentId":"14","title":"Standing"}]},{"id":"18","parentId":"7","title":"Aerobic","children":[{"id":"19","parentId":"18","title":"Cycling (Easy Spining)"},{"id":"20","parentId":"18","title":"Cross Trainer \/ Stepper"},{"id":"21","parentId":"18","title":"Supine \/ Sitting Weights"}]},{"id":"22","parentId":"7","title":"Water Based","children":[{"id":"23","parentId":"22","title":"Hydrotherapy"},{"id":"24","parentId":"22","title":"Deep Water Running"},{"id":"25","parentId":"22","title":"Shallow Water Jogging"},{"id":"26","parentId":"22","title":"Shallow Water Running"}]},{"id":"27","parentId":"7","title":"FWB weight lifting","children":[{"id":"28","parentId":"27","title":"Squats, Calf Raises, Lunges etc"},{"id":"29","parentId":"27","title":"Upper Limb"}]}]},{"id":"30","title":"SPORTS SPECIFIC","children":[{"id":"31","parentId":"30","title":"Running","children":[{"id":"35","parentId":"31","title":"Jogging"},{"id":"36","parentId":"31","title":"Running \/ Sprinting"},{"id":"37","parentId":"31","title":"Cutting \/ Turning"}]},{"id":"32","parentId":"30","title":"Batting","children":[{"id":"38","parentId":"32","title":"Shadow Batting"},{"id":"39","parentId":"32","title":"Batting Practice (nets)"},{"id":"40","parentId":"32","title":"Batting Match"}]},{"id":"33","parentId":"30","title":"Fielding Practice","children":[{"id":"41","parentId":"33","title":"Catching"},{"id":"42","parentId":"33","title":"Throwing"},{"id":"43","parentId":"33","title":"Running"}]},{"id":"34","parentId":"30","title":"Bowling","children":[{"id":"44","parentId":"34","title":"Drills"},{"id":"45","parentId":"34","title":"Short-run"},{"id":"46","parentId":"34","title":"Full-run"},{"id":"47","parentId":"34","title":"Bowling Match"}]}]},{"id":"1","title":"PHYSIO","children":[{"id":"4","parentId":"1","title":"Lx \/ tx Manual Therapy"},{"id":"6","parentId":"1","title":"LIPUS (Low intensity pulsed US -exogen)"}]},{"id":"3","title":"PHYSICAL Conditioning"}]
,
            events: [{"id":"1","resourceId":"8","desc":"crisp desc","title":"crisp","start":"2018-07-10 00:00:00","end":"2018-07-27 00:00:00"},{"id":"2","resourceId":"9","desc":"Crook Lying desc","title":"Crook Lying","start":"2018-07-03 00:00:00","end":"2018-08-17 23:00:00"}],
            eventRender: function (eventObj, $el) {
                $el.popover({
                    title: eventObj.title,
                    content: eventObj.desc,
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    placement: 'top',
                    container: 'body'
                });
            },
            dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view, resource) {

            },
            select: function (startDate, endDate, jsEvent, view, resource) {

            },
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just got the  answer reason i'm binding click event dynamically which initiate clone again  and again, so i  just unbind first  click    event and regenerate  next code.

```
 $(".antosubmit2").unbind('click').on("click",function (e) {
     code goes here
 });
```

Comment: Remember that you will use unbind() in eventDrop eventResize, eventClick and many other Methods.

Comment: in jQuery the opposite of "on" is "off". "unbind" is the opposite of "bind", but both of those methods are deprecated and shouldn't be used any longer. See http://api.jquery.com/unbind/ and http://api.jquery.com/off/